# Screwed width after appending

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to script a little chat for my website.
I'm using jQuery, bootstrap and ajax requests for this.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ng0gdrvq/4/)

After appending the new `<li>` the width is totally screwed for the appended element.
Hardcoding the size won't help.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: how can we see the problem you describe in your jsfiddle?

You get appended html from your server script, and it is not shown there

Comment: Same <li> like at jsfiddle...

Comment: adjust your jsfiddle to reproduce the problem

Comment: ok great, can we see it? The one in the quesion looks the same

Comment: Humm, didn't save :/ Will update later

Comment: Ok, updated now! Sorry for this :/ http://jsfiddle.net/ng0gdrvq/3/

Comment: I don't see any problem with the width, is it browser specific?

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: @nullability: See the fiddle O_O. mikehomme: My div has a fixed width of 250px. If you now type a looooong word, the fixed witdh is ignored. Tried word-wrap:break-word; but this didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Sry guys, really messed up my question.
It had nothing to do with the append();

Just happens with a string longer than 24 chars.

So I just did:

```
$content = chunk_split($content, 23, "\n\r");
```

Thanks anyways.